# How to Add New Row/Column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a game and I've been having a bit of trouble. What I'm trying to do is once all the blocks turn purple, I want to create a new row and column. I was trying to achieve this by removing all of the blocks after all the blocks were purple, and then create one more row and column than last time, using the variable rowVal. I've been working on JSFIddle and the link is http://jsfiddle.net/jaredasch1/6dhc240q/. I'll post the code down below just so you can look quickly

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <div id="button" class="on hover"></div>
    <br>
    <div class="block hover"></div>
    <div class="block hover"></div>
    <div class="block hover"></div>
    <div class="block hover"></div>
    <br>
    <div class="block hover"></div>
    <div class="block hover"></div>
    <div class="block hover"></div>
    <div class="block hover"></div>
    <br>
    <div class="block hover"></div>
    <div class="block hover"></div>
    <div class="block hover"></div>
    <div class="block hover"></div>
    <br>
    <div class="block hover"></div>
    <div class="block hover"></div>
    <div class="block hover"></div>
    <div class="block hover"></div>
</body>
```

The CSS

```
.block {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border-radius:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#33CCFF;
}
#button {
    height:100px;
    width:410px;
    border-radius:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#FF6666;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.on {
    background-color:#D633FF;
}
```

The JavaScript/ jQuery

```
var main = function () {
    var rowVal = 5;
    var setUp = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < rowVal; i++) {
            $("#button").append("<br>");
        }
        for (var k = 0; k < rowVal; k++) {
            $("<br>").append("<div class=\"block hover\"></div>");
        }
        rowVal++;
    };
    var checkAll = function () {
        var allDivs = $("div.block");
        var classedDivs = $("div.block.on");

        var allDivsHaveClass = (allDivs.length === classedDivs.length);

        if (allDivsHaveClass) {
            allDivs.remove(".on");
            setUp();
        }
    };
    $("div").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.25);
        $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
    });
    $("div").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
        $(this).css('cursor', 'default');
    });
    $(".block").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("on");
        $(this).prev().toggleClass("on");
        $(this).nextAll().eq(4).toggleClass("on");
        $(this).next().toggleClass("on");
        $(this).prevAll().eq(4).toggleClass("on");
        checkAll();
    });
    $("#button").click(function () {
        $(".block").removeClass("on");
    });
    $(document).keydown(function (key) {
        if (event.which === 32) {
            $(".block").removeClass("on");
        }
    });
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

I'm open to suggestions so please answer!

Comment: What problem are you having? What is it doing instead of what it's supposed to do?

Comment: Holy cow, this is slightly addicting.

Comment: @Barmar I want to add a clumn and row whenever checkAll = true

Answer (score 0):

In checkAll(), add the following:

```
$("body").append('<br><div class="block hover"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put each row into a div with class row and do the following:

```
var setUp = function () {
    $('.row').each(function(){
        $(this).prepend('<div class="block hover"></div>'); // add one more block to existing rows
    })
    $('body').append($('.row:eq(0)').clone()) // add one row
};
```

Here is full jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/juvian/6dhc240q/1/

Answer (score 0):

A small suggestion is to structure your HTML properly something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <div id="button" class="on hover"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
        <div class="block hover"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Then to append new column you can use

```
$('.row').each(function(){$(this).append('<div class="block hover"></div>');})
```

To add new row you can just clone the row

```
$('body').append($($('.row')[0]).clone())
```

Then $('.row').length would give number of rows and $($('.row')[0]).length would give number of columns

Comment: I tried that before, then what happens is that when ever I click one, the divs above and below don't change

Comment: To achieve this in `$(".block").click` instead of `$(this).nextAll().eq(4).toggleClass("on");` you can use `var col = $(this).siblings().index(this);`  `$(this).parent().prev().children().eq(col).toggleClass("on");`  and `$(this).parent().next().children().eq(col).toggleClass("on");`

Comment: This adds an extra row in the begining and screws up how the colors above and below change

Comment: then use prepend instead of append